# Keep UIView alway on top in app?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to keep a UIView on top of everything else in an app, even modals etc.?

Could it be done by having two UIWindows maybe or is there a recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Not possible to keep it on top of *everything*. Apple uses private UIWindows to render UIAlertViews, UIActionSheets, and the like. What are you after here?

Comment: I am trying to make a player window like the ones in the Spotify and Rdio apps, they overlap all other content (most of the time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have 2 windows in an application. But it is simply not recommended and we should avoid using multiple windows if we can. You can add a view on top of everything as a subview of the UIWindow as follows

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:viewName];
```

which should be not use often but you can have a view at the top of the view hierarchy by bringing it to the front as

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:viewName];
```

which brings the view to the front.

Comment: I wouldn't say you cannot have 2 windows in an application -- it's just not recommended.  I know of apps currently for sale on the App Store that have multiple UIWindows active at once. But I definitely wouldn't recommend it if you can avoid it.

Comment: @DennisMunsie I agree I cannot say 'You cannot have 2 windows in an application'. Editing the post...

Answer (score 1):

Try to add that view to the keyWindow of your application.
And then bring that view in front of keyWindow.
So...

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:yourView];

// your code here
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:yourView];
```